# pandas DataFrame split the column and extend the rows

Tags: python, pandas

like:

```
     A  B  C  D
  1  1  2  3  ['a','b']   
  2  4  6  7  ['b','c']
  3  1  0  1  ['a']
  4  2  1  1  ['b']
  5  1  2  3  []
```

to:

```
     A  B  C  D
  1  1  2  3  ['a']
  2  1  2  3  ['b']
  3  4  6  7  ['b']
  4  4  6  7  ['c']
  5  1  0  1  ['a']
  6  2  1  1  ['b']
  7  1  2  3  []
```

ps:  split the row in "D" and extend the row
use: pandas dataframe deal with the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a list comprehension with a doubly nest for-loop:

```
 >>> [(key + (item,)) 
      for key, val in df.set_index(['A','B','C'])['D'].iteritems()
      for item in map(list, val) or [[]]]

# [(1, 2, 3, ['a']),
#  (1, 2, 3, ['b']),
#  (4, 6, 7, ['b']),
#  (4, 6, 7, ['c']),
#  (1, 0, 1, ['a']),
#  (2, 1, 1, ['b']),
#  (1, 2, 3, [])]
```

Passing the data in this form to `pd.DataFrame` produces the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1},
 'B': {1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 2},
 'C': {1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 3},
 'D': {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['b', 'c'], 3: ['a'], 4: ['b'], 5: []}})
result = pd.DataFrame(
    [(key + (item,)) 
     for key, val in df.set_index(['A','B','C'])['D'].iteritems()
     for item in map(list, val) or [[]]])
```

yields

```
   0  1  2    3
0  1  2  3  [a]
1  1  2  3  [b]
2  4  6  7  [b]
3  4  6  7  [c]
4  1  0  1  [a]
5  2  1  1  [b]
6  1  2  3   []
```

---

Another option is to use `df['D'].apply` to expand the items in the list into different columns, and then use `stack` to expand the rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1},
 'B': {1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 2},
 'C': {1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 3},
 'D': {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['b', 'c'], 3: ['a'], 4: ['b'], 5: []}})
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])
result = df['D'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(map(list, x) if x else [[]]))
#          0    1
# A B C          
# 1 2 3  [a]  [b]
# 4 6 7  [b]  [c]
# 1 0 1  [a]  NaN
# 2 1 1  [b]  NaN
# 1 2 3   []  NaN

result = result.stack()
# A  B  C   
# 1  2  3  0    [a]
#          1    [b]
# 4  6  7  0    [b]
#          1    [c]
# 1  0  1  0    [a]
# 2  1  1  0    [b]
# 1  2  3  0     []
# dtype: object

result.index = result.index.droplevel(-1)
result = result.reset_index()
#    A  B  C    0
# 0  1  2  3  [a]
# 1  1  2  3  [b]
# 2  4  6  7  [b]
# 3  4  6  7  [c]
# 4  1  0  1  [a]
# 5  2  1  1  [b]
# 6  1  2  3   []
```

Although this does not use explicit `for-loop`s or a list comprehension, there is an implicit for-loop hidden in the call to `apply`. In fact, it is much slower than using a list comprehension:

```
In [170]: df = pd.concat([df]*10)

In [171]: %%timeit
   .....: result = df['D'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(map(list, x) if x else [[]]))
result = result.stack()
result.index = result.index.droplevel(-1)
result = result.reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop

In [172]: %%timeit
   .....: result = pd.DataFrame(
        [(key + (item,)) 
         for key, val in df['D'].iteritems()
         for item in map(list, val) or [[]]])
1000 loops, best of 3: 618 µs per loop
```

Comment: I want to know if not used the keywords "for",and how do it

Comment: Yes and no -- there is a way to do it using `apply/stack` which avoids the *explicit* double for-loops, but it is actually much slower than the list comprehension-based solution shown above. So if you are trying to avoid `for-loop`s for performance, then I don't think there is a good way. You see, when you put non-native NumPy data types, such as lists, in a DataFrame, ultimately computations on those values require plain Python methods which are relatively slow (compared to native NumPy methods). To break apart the items in the lists require plain Python loops no matter how you phrase it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `column` `D` content is of `type` `string`:

```
print(type(df.loc[0, 'D']))

<class 'str'>

df = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C']).sortlevel()
df.loc[:, 'D'] = df.loc[:, 'D'].str.strip('[').str.strip(']')
df = df.loc[:, 'D'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df = df.str.strip('').apply(lambda x: '[{}]'.format(x)).reset_index().drop('level_3', axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'D'})


   A  B  C      D
0  1  0  1  ['a']
1  1  2  3  ['a']
2  1  2  3  ['b']
3  1  2  3     []
4  2  1  1  ['b']
5  4  6  7  ['b']
6  4  6  7  ['c']
```

Comment: the other rows has change to Null

Comment: What exactly happened?